# How to seamlessly interact with a message broker when the underlying system (SQS, RabbitMQ) can change depending on the environment?

Tags: interfaces, message-queue, abstraction, hexagonal-architecture

Having a poor knowledge of the extended features of the available message brokers, I was wondering how to approach this.

We have some environments where only RabbitMQ is available, others where RabbitMQ and SQS are available.

For scalability reasons, we would like to be able to use SQS on environments where it is available.

I have two options in mind but I'm unsure of which one to pick.

First option would be to write an abstraction layer that would allow features to dispatch and receive messages without having to know what system is behind.

The second option would be to implement an adapter for each system per feature.

First option gives less flexibility about using specific features of a message broker, but allows for easy development of the features.

Second option allows to use the advanced functions of message brokers, but then we have to rewrite an adapter for each feature dispatching and receiving messages.

What option would be the best given this kind of setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: You should **write an abstraction layer** over message brokers.

Implementing adapters for F features × B broker vendors × 2 directions
will be No Fun.

---

If you can, start out with a BSD license for
the high level part that is unrelated to your app.
That will make it easier for you or someone else
to add Yet Another broker vendor, like kafka or 0mq.
That is to say, it may reduce your cost if someone else
really needs 0mq and you then adopt it as a nice-to-have.

---

You will need to write down the core functionality that
must be supplied to the app and that is common across vendors.
Start small, with just a few publish and subscribe primitives,
so you can get a prototype out the door.

Don't worry about throughput at this point, on the architectural assumption
that alternate vendor(s) and horizontal scaling can address that.
Do pay attention to latency, as you can never get those
lost milliseconds back.
And very much pay attention to correctness.

Write down the external persistence and external communication (SMTP?)
systems your use case will initially interact with.

Figure out the subset of delivery needs for your use case:

1. at most once
2. at least once
3. exactly once

If you need (2.), then your abstraction layer will have to be
generating nonces, such as GUIDs, for de-dup. This is duplicating
work that the underlying broker may be doing, but it is necessary
so that apps written to your abstraction layer will get uniform
semantics.

If you need (3.), then study how kafka and others have achieved
performant exactly-once delivery, and write down the responsibilities
for apps to be aware of message guids and to persist them or send
them to external communicating partners.

---

After demonstrating a working pub-sub system with defined delivery
semantics, next release would probably focus on reporting performance
stats like throughput and 95th percentile latency, in a uniform way
across brokers. This will offer valuable guidance on what each dollar
of installed capacity buys you at the app level, letting you
purchase the right amount of each vendor's offerings.

---

After that, I predict you will start punching holes
in your abstraction, and that is fine.
All abstractions are leaky abstractions.
With real-world deployment experience, and performance measurements,
you will understand your app's pain points, and can look around at
per-vendor options which address them.
This is a *little* like writing per-feature adapters,
in that your app's feature module needs to be aware
of details beyond just the portable abstraction layer
if it wants to take advantage of a performance tweak.
But it is entirely optional, and the feature should
still function in an environment where the tweak is not available.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer! I like the idea of starting with a simpler solution and adding complexity only when it becomes really necessary. I will evaluate the needs of the application following the guidelines you provided, there are some things I did not take into account yet. Thanks a lot!